# How to replicate a SAS merge

Tags: sql, merge, sas, outer-join

I have two tables, t1 and t2:

```
t1
  person | visit | code1 | type1
       1       1      50      50 
       1       1      50      50 
       1       2      75      50 

t2
  person | visit | code2 | type2
       1       1      50      50 
       1       1      50      50 
       1       1      50      50
```

When SAS runs the following code:

```
   DATA t3;
     MERGE t1 t2;
     BY person visit;

   RUN;
```

It generates the following dataset:

```
       person | visit | code1 | type1 | code2 | type2
            1       1      50      50      50      50
            1       1      50      50      50      50
            1       1      50      50      50      50
            1       2      75      50
```

I want to replicate this process in SQL, and my idea was to use a full-outer-join. This works unless there are duplicate rows. When we have duplicate rows like in the above example, a full outer join produces the following table:

```
       person | visit | code1 | type1 | code2 | type2
            1       1      50      50      50      50
            1       1      50      50      50      50
            1       1      50      50      50      50
            1       1      50      50      50      50
            1       1      50      50      50      50
            1       1      50      50      50      50
            1       2      75      50
```

I'm wondering how I would get the SQl table to match the SAS table.

Comment: is there a reason why you need to keep the duplicate rows?

Comment: How is this question different from [this question you posted earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32142858/difference-between-sas-merge-and-full-outer-join#comment52177904_32142858)?

Comment: @vkp yes, later on in the code it is summing over each person, visit group

Comment: @Joe I didn't really get an answer for the other question. I tried your suggestion, but must have misunderstood it because what I had wasn't working. I figured I would ask a more general form of the question here. Is this usually frowned upon? If so I apologize. The answer provided below was helpful.

Comment: Yes, you shouldn't have asked this question twice (which is so close as to not be any different).  Next time please edit the other question to be more general, if that's your intention, and you haven't received any useful answers.

Comment: What makes you think that the results of the existing process are correct?  Generally repeats of `by` values in both datasets results in in undesirable results when using merge.  That's why you get the note in the log `NOTE: MERGE statement has more than one data set with repeats of BY values.`

Comment: @RobertPenridge Could you elaborate on this? Are you saying that if there are duplicate     by values, the result will be hard to predict?

Comment: The results are highly predictable (assuming the order is predictable), but they may or may not be desirable.  Depends on the original system.  There are certainly times this particular method of merging is useful (getting the 'most recent value' of a particular row, when you normally would have same count on left/right, but occasionally won't have the newest right-side row yet, for example).  There are also many times this is undesirable.  A fair amount of the time, you want just the most recent right-side (or perhaps even right-side should never have duplicates, and that's an error).

Comment: @Danzo Basically what Joe said.  If I see this message generally it means I've done something wrong or I don't fully understand the data I'm working with.  Only rarely do I *expect* to see this message.  I just mention it because it may solve your actual problem, though it doesn't answer your specific question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gordon's answer is close; but it misses one point.  Here's its output:

```
person  visit   code1   type1   seqnum  person  visit   code2   type2   seqnum
1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1       1
1       1       2       2       2       1       1       2       2       2
NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1       1       3       3       3
1       2       1       3       1       NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

The third row's nulls are incorrect, while the fourth's are correct.

As far as I know, in SQL there's not a really good way to do this other than splitting things up into a few queries.  I think there are five possibilities:

- Matching person/visit, Matching seqnums
- Matching person/visit, Left has more seqnums
- Matching person/visit, Right has more seqnums
- Left has unmatched person/visit
- Right has unmatched person/visit

I think the last two might be workable into one query, but I think the second and third have to be separate queries.  You can union everything together, of course.

So here's an example, using some temporary tables that are a little more well suited to see what's going on.  Note that the third row is now filled in for `code1` and `type1`, even though those are 'extra'.  I've only added three of the five criteria - the three you had in your initial example - but the other two aren't too hard.

Note that this is an example of something *far* faster in SAS - because SAS has a row-wise concept, ie, it's capable of going one row at a time.  SQL tends to take a lot longer at these, with large tables, unless it's possible to partition things very neatly and have very good indexes - and even then I've never seen a SQL DBA do anywhere near as well as SAS at some of these types of problems.  That's something you'll have to accept of course - SQL has its own advantages, one of which being probably price...

Here's my example code.  I'm sure it's not terribly elegant, hopefully one of the SQL folk can improve it.  This is written to work in SQL Server (using table variables), same thing should work with some changes (to use temporary tables) in other variants, assuming they implement windowing.  (SAS of course can't do this particular thing - as even FedSQL implements ANSI 1999, not ANSI 2008.)  This is based on Gordon's initial query, then modified with the additional bits at the end.  Anyone who wants to improve this please feel free to edit and/or copy to a new/existing answer any bit you wish.

```
declare @t1 table (person INT, visit INT, code1 INT, type1 INT);
declare @t2 table (person INT, visit INT, code2 INT, type2 INT);


insert into @t1 values (1,1,1,1)
insert into @t1 values (1,1,2,2)
insert into @t1 values (1,2,1,3)

insert into @t2 values (1,1,1,1)
insert into @t2 values (1,1,2,2)
insert into @t2 values (1,1,3,3)

select coalesce(t1.person, t2.person) as person, coalesce(t1.visit, t2.visit) as visit,
                t1.code1, t1.type1, t2.code2, t2.type2
from (select *,
             row_number() over (partition by person, visit order by type1) as seqnum
      from @t1
     ) t1 inner join
     (select *,
             row_number() over (partition by person, visit order by type2) as seqnum
      from @t2
     ) t2
     on t1.person = t2.person and t1.visit = t2.visit and
        t1.seqnum = t2.seqnum
 union all

select coalesce(t1.person, t2.person) as person, coalesce(t1.visit, t2.visit) as visit,
                t1.code1, t1.type1, t2.code2, t2.type2
from (
      (select person, visit, MAX(seqnum) as max_rownum from (
        select person, visit, 
             row_number() over (partition by person, visit order by type1) as seqnum
      from @t1) t1_f 
      group by person, visit
     ) t1_m inner join
     (select *, row_number() over (partition by person, visit order by type1) as seqnum
       from @t1
      ) t1 
        on t1.person=t1_m.person and t1.visit=t1_m.visit
        and t1.seqnum=t1_m.max_rownum
        inner join
     (select *,
             row_number() over (partition by person, visit order by type2) as seqnum
      from @t2
     ) t2
     on t1.person = t2.person and t1.visit = t2.visit and
        t1.seqnum < t2.seqnum 
     )
 union all
 select t1.person, t1.visit, t1.code1, t1.type1, t2.code2, t2.type2
     from @t1 t1 left join @t2 t2
    on t2.person=t1.person and t2.visit=t1.visit
    where t2.code2 is null
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replicate a SAS merge by adding a `row_number()` to each table:

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from (select t1.*,
             row_number() over (partition by person, visit order by ??) as seqnum
      from t1
     ) t1 full outer join
     (select t2.*,
             row_number() over (partition by person, visit order by ??) as seqnum
      from t2
     ) t2
     on t1.person = t2.person and t1.visit = t2.visit and
        t1.seqnum = t2.seqnum;
```

Notes:

- The `??` means to put in the column(s) used for ordering.  SAS datasets have an intrinsic order.  SQL tables do not, so the ordering needs to be specified.
- You should list the columns explicitly (instead of using `t1.*, t2.*` in the outer query).  I think SAS only includes `person` and `visit` once in the resulting dataset.

EDIT:

Note:  the above produces separate values for the key columns.  This is easy enough to fix:

```
select coalesce(t1.person, t2.person) as person,
       coalesce(t1.key, t2.key) as key,
       t1.code1, t1.type1, t2.code2, t2.type2
from (select t1.*,
             row_number() over (partition by person, visit order by ??) as seqnum
      from t1
     ) t1 full outer join
     (select t2.*,
             row_number() over (partition by person, visit order by ??) as seqnum
      from t2
     ) t2
     on t1.person = t2.person and t1.visit = t2.visit and
        t1.seqnum = t2.seqnum;
```

That fixes the columns issue.  You can fix the copying issue by using `first_value()`/`last_value()` or by using a more complicated `join` condition:

```
select coalesce(t1.person, t2.person) as person,
       coalesce(t1.visit, t2.visit) as visit,
       t1.code1, t1.type1, t2.code2, t2.type2
from (select t1.*,
             count(*) over (partition by person, visit) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by person, visit order by ??) as seqnum
      from t1
     ) t1 full outer join
     (select t2.*,
             count(*) over (partition by person, visit) as cnt,
             row_number() over (partition by person, visit order by ??) as seqnum
      from t2
     ) t2
     on t1.person = t2.person and t1.visit = t2.visit and
        (t1.seqnum = t2.seqnum or
        (t1.cnt > t2.cnt and t1.seqnum > t2.seqnum and t2.seqnum = t2.cnt) or
        (t2.cnt > t1.cnt and t2.seqnum > t1.seqnum and t1.seqnum = t1.cnt)
```

This implements the "keep the last row" logic in a single join.  Probably for performance reasons, you would want to put this into separate `left join`s on the original logic.

Comment: This doesn't *perfectly* replicate it, though, does it?  If `T1` has 2 lines and `T2` has 3 lines for a particular ID grouping, SAS would have `T1.seqnum=2` copied onto `T2.seqnum=3`.  I think you'd have to do this for `inner join` and then add a second (and possibly third) table that is the `T1.seqnum > max(T2.seqnum)` for each grouping, and perhaps `T2.seqnum > max(T1.seqnum)`, joined to their respective max.seqnum rows.

Comment: Do you mean replace the full outer join in the above code with an inner join, then do an inner join with the two tables where t1.seqnum > max(t2.seqnum) and t2.seqnum>max(t1.seqnum)? @Joe

Comment: Above inner join, then union to another join or two (each union).