# Reproducing SAS merge in R

Tags: r, join, merge, sas

I feel very stupid.  I am trying to replicate a colleague's data processing in R.  She used SAS.  Should be easy, right?

Well, I can't duplicate her datastep merge.  It's not even a complicated merge.  Just the natural inner join that it produces.

This is the simple SAS code:

```
data dataC;
    merge dataA dataB;
    by facility facilityuid;
run;
```

And it produces this:

[image]

Here's a little bit of the datasets and the code I've been trying.  Note, the datasets don't have the same number of rows, both here and in my actual data.

```
dataA <- data.frame(structure(list(facility = structure(c("1 de Maio CS", "1 de Maio CS", 
"1 de Maio CS", "16 de Junho CS", "16 de Junho CS", "16 de Junho CS", 
"17 de Setembro CS", "17 de Setembro CS", "17 de Setembro CS", 
"1º Maio CS", "1º Maio CS", "1º Maio CS", "1º de Junho CS", "1º de Junho CS", 
"1º de Junho CS", "1º de Maio CS", "1º de Maio CS", "1º de Maio CS", 
"24 de Julho CS", "24 de Julho CS", "24 de Julho CS", "25 de Setembro CS", 
"25 de Setembro CS", "25 de Setembro CS", "25 de Setembro CS", 
"25 de Setembro CS", "25 de Setembro CS", "25 de Setembro CS", 
"3 Fevereiro CS", "3 de Fevereiro CS"), label = "facility", format.sas = "$"), 
    facilityuid = structure(c("uBjjsyieqtr", "uBjjsyieqtr", "uBjjsyieqtr", 
    "rpmWXDmHjsq", "rpmWXDmHjsq", "rpmWXDmHjsq", "fJy2O3xh1fV", 
    "fJy2O3xh1fV", "fJy2O3xh1fV", "l7dBO27dhA6", "l7dBO27dhA6", 
    "l7dBO27dhA6", "wXnoTA2MDy9", "wXnoTA2MDy9", "wXnoTA2MDy9", 
    "oDTFc2FqImi", "oDTFc2FqImi", "oDTFc2FqImi", "vniKeY4S1Ru", 
    "vniKeY4S1Ru", "vniKeY4S1Ru", "WUFgPdTN02g", "WUFgPdTN02g", 
    "WUFgPdTN02g", "cGvhZR5kDxQ", "cGvhZR5kDxQ", "j8DdqpZn2qc", 
    "j8DdqpZn2qc", "Ca2rjTu7g6A", "rnGH1Q5IyIU"), label = "facilityuid", format.sas = "$"), 
    totalPVLS_NQ4 = structure(c(NA, 2019, 2713, NA, 556, 856, 
    2805, NA, 2381, 1919, NA, 3352, 1299, NA, 4769, NA, 2576, 
    6268, 1512, NA, 1617, NA, 2292, 4389, NA, 89, NA, 197, NA, 
    76), label = "qtr4", format.sas = "BEST")), row.names = c(NA, 
-30L), class = "data.frame", label = "A"))

dataB <- data.frame(structure(list(facility = structure(c("1 de Maio CS", "1 de Maio CS", 
"1 de Maio CS", "1 de Maio CS", "16 de Junho CS", "16 de Junho CS", 
"16 de Junho CS", "16 de Junho CS", "17 de Setembro CS", "17 de Setembro CS", 
"17 de Setembro CS", "17 de Setembro CS", "1º Maio CS", "1º Maio CS", 
"1º Maio CS", "1º Maio CS", "1º de Junho CS", "1º de Junho CS", 
"1º de Junho CS", "1º de Junho CS"), label = "facility", format.sas = "$"), 
    facilityuid = structure(c("uBjjsyieqtr", "uBjjsyieqtr", "uBjjsyieqtr", 
    "uBjjsyieqtr", "rpmWXDmHjsq", "rpmWXDmHjsq", "rpmWXDmHjsq", 
    "rpmWXDmHjsq", "fJy2O3xh1fV", "fJy2O3xh1fV", "fJy2O3xh1fV", 
    "fJy2O3xh1fV", "l7dBO27dhA6", "l7dBO27dhA6", "l7dBO27dhA6", 
    "l7dBO27dhA6", "wXnoTA2MDy9", "wXnoTA2MDy9", "wXnoTA2MDy9", 
    "wXnoTA2MDy9"), label = "facilityuid", format.sas = "$"), 
    totalPVLS_DQ4 = structure(c(3186, NA, NA, 3562, 746, NA, 
    1050, NA, 3535, NA, NA, 2957, NA, 2405, NA, 4096, 1604, NA, 
    NA, 5404), label = "qtr4", format.sas = "BEST")), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = "data.frame", label = "B"))

dataC <- plyr::join(dataA, dataB, type = "inner")

dataC <- merge(dataA, dataB, by=c("facility","facilityuid"))
```

With either join or merge, specifying an inner join, I get this data:

[image]

I cannot replicate the SAS version.  Now, in my opinion neither outcome makes any sense.  These data SHOULD be combined using rbind.fill.  But, I do need to fully replicate what my colleague has done so I can steer her in the right direction going forward.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this the same data you used in `SAS`.  I find duplicates for both datasets `dataA %>% dplyr::count(facility, facilityuid)` and `dataB %>% dplyr::count(facility, facilityuid)` If there is no unique key, it would create issues in matching

Comment: I agree there are issues with this data.  That's what I am trying to help her with.  The unique key is supposed to be the facilityuid but there shouldn't be more than one entry for either totalPVLS_NQ4 or totalPVLS_DQ4 for each facility but there is.  But, I need to reproduce her work so I can discuss the data issues with another colleague that works exclusively in R.

Comment: Can you show the full output of SAS from that input data.

Comment: @akrun, I have in the response below.  Apologies for putting it in a response.

Comment: Are you getting 39 rows from SAS output

Comment: No, the total dataset size is 3516 rows.

Comment: ok, i think the default `merge` method in SAS is doing a full_join.  Please check [here](https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings09/036-2009.pdf)

Comment: Perhaps `full_join(dataA, dataB, by=c("facility","facilityuid")) %>% filter(rowSums(across(ends_with("Q4"), ~ is.na(.))) < 2)`

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't do it, either.   From what I read SAS does a natural join, a kind of inner join, when nothing is specified (eg, merge dataA (in=A) dataB (in=B))

Comment: sorry, I don't have SAS to test what is going on behind the hood

Comment: Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: @philipxy Not helpful.  I did these things.

Comment: There is no SAS [mre] & there are images that should be text & there is no clear statement of your problem you could have googled etc. "in my opinion neither outcome makes any sense" But you don't say what you expect & why, etc etc. PS Please clarify via edits, not comments. Anyway, good luck.

Comment: Here is link to similar question about how to replicate the SAS data step MERGE with SQL.  That should help clarify the question and also show the outline of how to build a solution in R.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32256096/how-to-replicate-a-sas-merge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sample data, a SAS merge merges every row of data in the first data set at least once with the data in the second data set, based on the sort order of the by groups.

After writing the sample data to CSV and reading it back into SAS, the data step that merges the data results in 35 observations.

```
filename data_a "/folders/myfolders/data/dataA.csv";
filename data_b "/folders/myfolders/data/dataB.csv";

data dataA;
  infile data_a dlm="," firstobs = 2;
  input facility $ facilityuid $ totalPVLS_NQ;
  run;

data dataB;
  /* read starting second row */ 
  infile data_b dlm="," firstobs = 2;
  input facility $ facilityuid $ totalPVLS_DQ;
  run;

/* sort data */
proc sort data = dataA;
   by facility facilityuid;
run;

proc sort data = dataB;
   by facility facilityuid;
run; 

/*
 * merge the two data sets
 */

data both;
  merge dataA(in=inA) dataB(in=inB);
  by facility facilityuid;
  in_a = inA;
  in_b = inB;
run;
```

For the first by group, since there are three observations in `dataA` and four observations in `dataB` with the key `1 de Mai   uBjjsyie`, the output data set `both` contains 4 rows with this key. We've assigned two new variables to capture the data from the `in =`option to illustrate which data set contributed to the output, and printed it.

```
proc print data = both;
run;
```

[image]

From the printout we can see that the third row from `dataA` was duplicated to match it with the fourth row from `dataB`.

The default behavior of the R `merge()` function is to perform a cartesian product between every row in `dataA` where the by variables match `dataB`. Since there are three rows in `dataA` and four rows in `dataB` where the key is `1 de Mai uBjjsyie`, we print the first 12 rows of the output to illustrate the cartesian product of the data.

```
dataC <- merge(dataA, dataB, by=c("facility","facilityuid"))
head(dataC,n = 12)

       facility facilityuid totalPVLS_NQ4 totalPVLS_DQ4
1  1 de Maio CS uBjjsyieqtr          2713          3186
2  1 de Maio CS uBjjsyieqtr          2713            NA
3  1 de Maio CS uBjjsyieqtr          2713            NA
4  1 de Maio CS uBjjsyieqtr          2713          3562
5  1 de Maio CS uBjjsyieqtr            NA          3186
6  1 de Maio CS uBjjsyieqtr            NA            NA
7  1 de Maio CS uBjjsyieqtr            NA            NA
8  1 de Maio CS uBjjsyieqtr            NA          3562
9  1 de Maio CS uBjjsyieqtr          2019          3186
10 1 de Maio CS uBjjsyieqtr          2019            NA
11 1 de Maio CS uBjjsyieqtr          2019            NA
12 1 de Maio CS uBjjsyieqtr          2019          3562
>
```

Even `dplyr` join functions use a cartesian product to resolve multiple matches between `dataA` and `dataB`, so we are unable to exactly replicate the SAS output in R solely with an "out of the box" R function. When we read the help for `mutate-joins`, we find the following.

> mutate-joins {dplyr}   R Documentation
>   Mutating joins
>   Description
>   The mutating joins add columns from y to x, matching rows based on the keys:
>
> inner_join(): includes all rows in x and y.
>
> left_join(): includes all rows in x.
>
> right_join(): includes all rows in y.
>
> full_join(): includes all rows in x or y.
>
> If a row in x matches multiple rows in y, all the rows in y will be returned once for each matching row in x

The cartesian product effect is consistent across `left_join()`, `inner_join()`, `full_join()` and `right_join()`.

```
library(dplyr)
dataA %>% right_join(.,dataB)  -> dataD
head(dataD,n = 12)
```

...and the output:

```
> head(dataD,n = 12)
       facility facilityuid totalPVLS_NQ4 totalPVLS_DQ4
1  1 de Maio CS uBjjsyieqtr            NA          3186
2  1 de Maio CS uBjjsyieqtr            NA            NA
3  1 de Maio CS uBjjsyieqtr            NA            NA
4  1 de Maio CS uBjjsyieqtr            NA          3562
5  1 de Maio CS uBjjsyieqtr          2019          3186
6  1 de Maio CS uBjjsyieqtr          2019            NA
7  1 de Maio CS uBjjsyieqtr          2019            NA
8  1 de Maio CS uBjjsyieqtr          2019          3562
9  1 de Maio CS uBjjsyieqtr          2713          3186
10 1 de Maio CS uBjjsyieqtr          2713            NA
11 1 de Maio CS uBjjsyieqtr          2713            NA
12 1 de Maio CS uBjjsyieqtr          2713          3562
>
```

**Bottom line:** one needs to clean the data to eliminate or resolve the duplicates for `facilityuid` in both `dataA` and `dataB`.

For example, is it acceptable to eliminate rows where `totalPVLS_DQ4` is `NA` in `dataB` or where `totalPVLS_NQ4` in `dataA` is `NA`?  Can we add a sequential identifier to each file, assuming that the multiple observations for a facility were taken in the sequential order in the file?

If we take the above listed questions as constraints, we can join the data from the two files as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
dataA %>% filter(!is.na(totalPVLS_NQ4)) %>% group_by(.,facility,facilityuid) %>% 
     mutate(., n = seq_along(facilityuid)) -> dataA
dataB %>% filter(!is.na(totalPVLS_DQ4)) %>% group_by(.,facility,facilityuid) %>% 
     mutate(., n = seq_along(facilityuid)) %>%
     full_join(.,dataA) -> resultData 
resultData
```

...and the output:

```
# A tibble: 19 x 5
# Groups:   facility, facilityuid [11]
   facility          facilityuid totalPVLS_DQ4     n totalPVLS_NQ4
   <chr>             <chr>               <dbl> <int>         <dbl>
 1 1 de Maio CS      uBjjsyieqtr          3186     1          2019
 2 1 de Maio CS      uBjjsyieqtr          3562     2          2713
 3 16 de Junho CS    rpmWXDmHjsq           746     1           556
 4 16 de Junho CS    rpmWXDmHjsq          1050     2           856
 5 17 de Setembro CS fJy2O3xh1fV          3535     1          2805
 6 17 de Setembro CS fJy2O3xh1fV          2957     2          2381
 7 1º Maio CS        l7dBO27dhA6          2405     1          1919
 8 1º Maio CS        l7dBO27dhA6          4096     2          3352
 9 1º de Junho CS    wXnoTA2MDy9          1604     1          1299
10 1º de Junho CS    wXnoTA2MDy9          5404     2          4769
11 1º de Maio CS     oDTFc2FqImi            NA     1          2576
12 1º de Maio CS     oDTFc2FqImi            NA     2          6268
13 24 de Julho CS    vniKeY4S1Ru            NA     1          1512
14 24 de Julho CS    vniKeY4S1Ru            NA     2          1617
15 25 de Setembro CS WUFgPdTN02g            NA     1          2292
16 25 de Setembro CS WUFgPdTN02g            NA     2          4389
17 25 de Setembro CS cGvhZR5kDxQ            NA     1            89
18 25 de Setembro CS j8DdqpZn2qc            NA     1           197
19 3 de Fevereiro CS rnGH1Q5IyIU            NA     1            76
>
```

Comment: "we are unable to exactly replicate the SAS output in R" Well, as I'm sure you would agree, it can be done in R, just not necessarily via only a join or merge call with no other calls, depending on whether there's an implicit index or known keys or neither. The behaviour of the given SAS merge is a sort of side by side concatenation & we can expect that to be a SO R faq. Moreover, considering there's no SAS [mre] & no input for the given SAS output & no specified limit to the input & it's strangely called a "natural join" by the asker, it's not clear what they are actually asking for.

Comment: @philipxy - I was a bit imprecise in my original text. What I meant was "we are unable to replicate the SAS output with an "out of box" R function. The behavior of the given SAS merge is based on the way SAS manages what is called "by group processing," and it's based on 50 year old record oriented data processing. SAS has other techniques that work like R `merge()` or `dplyr::???_join()` but they weren't used in the OP.

Comment: Yes, it would be good for you to be clear about what "we are unable" to do under what constraints. I don't see how the rest of you comment addresses my comment, since mine is re R functionality for the asker's requested SAS functionality, not vice versa. And since whatever the asker is asking for can be coded in R, regardless of the input, contrary to your alleged "bottom line", this doesn't answer the question. Or maybe you think the asker imposes certain constraints on what form the input and/or the answer expression can take, but I don't see that made clear in your answer or the question.

Comment: @philipxy - the data has ambiguities that require additional input from the OP. That said, with some simplifying assumptions, yes we can merge the data in R as noted in the update to my answer.

Comment: @LenGreski, this is fantastic!  Thanks so much!  I agree the data is very messy.  I intend to do something about that as soon as I can replicate the work my colleague has done (with messy data).  This is not an approach I would normally take.

Comment: @JensabbyATL - you're welcome. If you found my answer to be helpful, please accept & upvote it.

Comment: @LenGreski, this answer doesn't get me to replicating SAS but it does explain clearly why I can't, which is good enough for me to go to my next step.

Comment: @JensabbyATL - thanks. I could write a custom R script to manually merge the two files, but it's a lot of work for something that would only be used once.

Comment: @LenGreski, that is definitely not necessary!  I was just bewildered as to why I couldn't make them match.  I am not a fan of SAS's merge method.  It produces data that doesn't make sense (given it's messy data).

Comment: This is a great solution!